# Countable sets in $\mathbb R$ are Borel sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am aware that this is a very general question, but why is every countable set in the real numbers a Borel set?

Comment: Do you know what "Borel set" means?

Comment: And no, this isn't a very general question. This is a very specific question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Every singleton is a Borel set, $\{x\}=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}(x-\frac1n,x+\frac1n)$.

And the countable union of Borel sets is a Borel set.

Comment: thank you! with more or less the same approach I could show now that countable sets in R have measure zero.

Comment: @asaf karagila; can't we say singleton {a} is Borel set by just using a simple fact that $\mathbb{R}-\set{0}$ is Borel (being open) hence its complement {a} is Borel

Comment: @Ibs: I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: @asaf; I am saying that {a} is Borel since R-{a} is open(and hence Borel,taking its complement is again Borel),instead using infinite intersection to show that singleton is borel

Comment: @Ibs: Yes, that is one way of doing it; note that in some places Borel sets are generated by open intervals, not open sets, which would formally require you to first prove that $\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$ is a union of intervals, and therefore $\{x\}$ is Borel.

Comment: @asaf; I think saying "Borel algebra is generated by open sets is same as it is generated by open intervals" as we can reduce our generating set ,both generates same algebra, isn't?

Comment: @Ibs: Yes, those are the same; you can also say it's generated by the closed sets; etc. But once you have a definition, you need to use it. Since there was no definition given, I went with a broadly applicable answer (to the best of my memory from nearly a decade ago).

Comment: @asaf; yes,thanks